# Why does Update Manager give me an "unable to mark upgrades" error?

Tags: updates, kde

I am getting the following error (in the screen shot)

[image]

when I try to install updates. Can someone explain to me why this is happening and possibly offer a way to fix it?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This message is not unusual, because the packages shown in the screenshot (Linux kernel, headers, image) are "meta-packages", which will pull in the latest version of the Linux kernel/headers/image when they are installed. Those are the "new packages" that the message is warning you need to be installed.

It should be safe to just click on "Mark Upgrades" and proceed. If you get any further errors, please edit your question with the new information.

Comment: So I did this and now KDE won't boot, any other ideas?

Comment: "Won't boot" as in how? Errors? Warnings? Etc.

Comment: it gets to the splash screen and just spins and spins... never doing anything.... no errors or anything...

Comment: Can you press Esc while on the splash screen to switch to text mode which should show any obvious issues?

Comment: I will give that a go when I get a chance....

Comment: I did as you asked (pressed escape) and Ubuntu launched... odd but I hope it is fixed :-D Thanks for the help